# Impressive Examples of Progressive Enhancement

Tags: progressive-enhancement

I see the value in using progressive enhancement in web development and I already use it regularly. That said, almost every website I've seen that strongly advocates progressive enhancement is a website with no images that has a div for a title and a div for navigation -- in other words, really basic (and boring) stuff.

Do you know of any examples of sites that use progressive enhancement to great effect? I love poking around disabling all sorts of things on sites to see what they look like but I rarely find something that degrades beautifully. I'm looking for something with images, dynamic content, tables, embedded players, or anything somewhat more tricky to develop than just blocks of text.

I'm still waiting to find that site that displays perfectly in text-only browsers and still blows me away in its full-featured glory ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Amazon site degrades quite well.

If JavaScript is off, then it is still possible to browse through product pictures (with full page reload of course). If JavaScript is on, then the nice Ajax improves the experience.

Comment: I disabled CSS on Amazon and got the message: "A different version of this web site containing similar content optimized for screen readers and mobile devices may be found at the web address: www.amazon.com/access". Very cool :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're reading on one!  4877 revisions and counting.

Comment: Sorry, I think I misunderstood what PE meant.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [www.yahoo.com](http://www.yahoo.com) - it based on YUI library ([yuilibrary.com](http://yuilibrary.com)) made by themselves. It has a wide range of widgets, modules that have progressive inhancement by design. ( I checked their site WITH and WITHOUT scripts enabled - and even didnt recognize the difference, really - did that twice to make sure that I disabled them %-)

UPD: For tables check [this link](http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/examples/datatable/dt_enhanced_clean.html) for Tables that use "Progressive Enhancement" with scripts enabled or degrades without them.

Answer (score 0):

A really great example as how to progressive enhance a view

http://www.alistapart.com/articles/testdriven/

Answer (score 0):

The Filament Group designed boston**globe**.com using progressive-enhancement. It, of course, has images, canvas, video, etc.